# Sharepoint is showing "working on it" for no reason

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

Sometimes when i am trying to fill up a form in sharepoint webparts, suddenly sharepoint will show "working on it" and reload the page so my entered data will gone. why it is happening and how can i stop it or at least keep my entered data?

**sharepoint is showing this:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check if you have some custom code in the list form. Using IE F12 to check if some error messages occurs.

Create a new custom list and check if the error occurs.

And check the ULS log to get more information, for SharePoint 2016, by default, ULS log locates in 
"**C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS**"